# Cypher Truncate Chain

Tags: neo4j, cypher, truncate, chain

I would like to cut the last node from a chain `p`. I get `p` by a query like this `MATCH p=(A)-[*0..]->(B)-[*1..]->(C)`. I need `(C)` to identify the correct chain but I do not wan `(C)` *in* the chain. Can I somehow remove it from the selection `p`? (I do not wanr to remove it from the graph, just from the selection `p`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original query looks like this:

```
MATCH p=(a:A)-[*0..]->(b:B)-[*]->(c:C)
RETURN p;
```

You can do this, instead, to get what you want:

```
MATCH p=(A)-[*0..]->(B)-[*]->(x)
WHERE (x)-->(c:C)
RETURN p;
```